# How to troubleshoot pyinstaller exe not working

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've built a small Python app that compares a set of files to a SQL query and delivers any differences to an excel file.  I used pyinstaller to wrap up the code and libraries so I can deploy it to a server where it'll live and run.

The exe from pyinstaller works great on my local machine but doesn't work at all after transferring to the server.  The installed Python versions are the same (3.8.5) and I don't get errors or logs.  My code has good error handling so I'd expect that if any of my errors were triggered I'd get the error file but I'm not getting one.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons that could be causing the issue, but most importantly, Python scripts are not an exe, i.e. a windows executable.

Python scripts are run by the Python interpreter, so you need a .py file to be interpreted by the Python installation in the server.

Start by installing Python correctly in the server and seeing if you can run scripts, etc. Then upload your script and run it.

Comment: The issue I'm running into is that my install server is completely offline - I cannot run PIP or anything else to install the necessary libraries to make my script run.  Therefore I was attempting to use pyinstaller to include the libraries/modules needed to make the app run.

Comment: That would be a different question then, "How to deploy a Python program to a computer that's offline and has no Python installed?", maybe look into creating an egg or wheel in addition to the Python installer, etc.